# Cloudflares rocket script

Tags: cloudflare, rocketscript

I saw some code for something called rocketscript. I searched the name and it only came up with stuff about WordPress, but I finally found something on the cloudflare website. It just gives information about what it is, and what it does, I seen on another site that the snippet of code they have like the one below is custom, and has their domain / a unique id in it.

I was wondering how can I get my own code for my website? I can't find any page where cloudflare will give me the code, or tell me how to implement it into my website, do I just copy the code from another website? I don't think I do as each code has the websites domain and a unique id.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
try{if (!window.CloudFlare) {var CloudFlare=[{verbose:0,p:0,byc:0,owlid:"cf",bag2:1,mirage2:0,oracle:0,paths:{cloudflare:"/cdn-cgi/nexp/dok3v=1613a3a185/"},atok:"0c520450ae00f93ad3c6d427e6175e11",petok:"39b2bad3263429bff6b9dfc54bc4b070f517b5df-1443920379-1800",zone:"fabborp.co.uk",rocket:"a",apps:0}];document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/nexp/dok3v=e9627cd26a/cloudflare.min.js"><'+'\/script>');}}catch(e){};
//]]>
</script>
<script type="text/rocketscript">
//<![CDATA[
try{if (!window.CloudFlare) {var CloudFlare=[{verbose:0,p:0,byc:0,owlid:"cf",bag2:1,mirage2:0,oracle:0,paths:{cloudflare:"/cdn-cgi/nexp/dok3v=1613a3a185/"},atok:"cc7792bcd37b11acfe5d52854c3c31cb",petok:"60a72fe01a43af4ce7bfedbb9aa1557bd41221e9-1437754506-1800",betok:"b5597544ec58644c04609e45c7005743deab17c5-1437754506-120",zone:"fabborp.co.uk",rocket:"a",apps:0}];document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/nexp/dok3v=e6ea9bd6c9/cloudflare.min.js"><'+'\/script>');}}catch(e){};
//]]>
</script>
```

Main question is, how do I get my OWN code? for rocketshare..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudFlare's Rocket Loader system...

> is a general-purpose asynchronous JavaScript loader coupled with a lightweight virtual browser which can safely run any JavaScript code after window.onload.

You can use Rocket Loader by adding the website you would like to enable Rocket Loader on to CloudFlare. CloudFlare automatically adds the code to every page on your website using DNS, no need for you to add it in yourself.

1. [Sign up for CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/a/sign-up).

   - Add your website to CloudFlare using CloudFlare's easy to use wizard that should appear after you login.
2. Select your site from the list that should appear on your screen. A list may not appear as you have only one site in your account.
3. Select 'Speed' in the navigation bar:
   [image: Navigation bar image]
4. Scroll down to Rocket Loader and select the desired option, probably Automatic.
5. Give it a little while to propagate, stuff like this doesn't happen instantly.

Hope that works for you!

Comment: More information in [CloudFlare's Knowledgebase](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168056-What-does-Rocket-Loader-do-).

Comment: This helped a lot, can you tell me the different between automatic and manual though?

Comment: @JoshHallow - CloudFlare's Knowledgebase article states that 'Automatic' mode will automatically try to make every script run faster on your pages unless the `data-cfasync='false'` attribute is passed before the `src` attribute on the Javascript tag you wish to disable Rocket Loader on. 'Manual' mode will add the Rocket Loader script to each page, but will not run Rocket Loader (therefore will not speed up your Javascript) unless you pass the `data-cfasync='true'` before the `src` attribute on the Javascript tag you wish to enable Rocket Loader on. Hope this helps.